# search two value in a list of tuples containing three values in python

Tags: python-3.7

```
[('12121212', 'computer', 'computer@123'), ('1223', 'asus', 'asus@123'), ('1111', 'testpro', 'testpro@123')]
```

I want to get one value from the tuple in list if I will input other two values present in tuple in python.
Suppose  fvalue=computer and svalue=12121212 then I will get tvalue as computer@123

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Maybe an example?

Comment: Please specify what do you want to achieve; Can you provide some example?

Comment: From your example I understand that you want a function with 2 words as input that finds which of the tuples contain these 2 words in any three positions. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if i understand what you want. This will search the tuple that has your 2 values and return the third.

```
a = [('12121212', 'computer', 'computer@123'), ('1223', 'asus', 'asus@123'), ('1111', 'testpro', 'testpro@123')]

value1 = '1111'
value2 = 'testpro@123'


def search(val1, val2, list_to_search):
    for item in list_to_search:
        if val1 in item and val2 in item:
            item = list(item)
            item.remove(val1)
            item.remove(val2)

            return item[0]
    return None


print(search(value1, value2, a))
```

Result: `testpro`